# Unit Test for calling stored procedure

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method that calls the stored procedure using Entity Framework and returns the query result.

How I can write a unit test for this method? I am not sure how mock the call and return values.

Stored procedure is returning me 3 columns.

```
public VerifyUser VerifyUser(string accountKey)
{
    try
    {
        LoansContext loansContext = new LoansContext();

        VerifyUser queryResult = null;

        using (loansContext)
        {
            using (loansContext.Database.Connection)
            {
                loansContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                string sqlStatment = string.Format("{0} @AccountKey = '{1}'", "execute [Loan].[Proc_VerifyUser]", accountKey);

                queryResult = loansContext.Database
                                  .SqlQuery<VerifyUser>(sqlStatment)
                                  .Single();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        LoansDomainTrace.Trace.Error(EventId.Retrieve,
             () => string.Format("VerifyUser exception: {0}", exception.Message), exception);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're doing raw SQL, I don't think there's much point in trying to mock this out as you'd have to intercept and mock so much infrastructure to abstract away connections, checking the query etc. One approach you could try instead is to use something like SQL LocalDB and deploy a test database to it and then give the connection string to that test database to the test class so it can connect to it, and then actually exercise your SQL code against a "real" database. I've used this approach in the past. It's not a *pure* unit test as it needs a database, but is repeatable and is all local

Comment: Unit tests test behavior. What behavior are you trying to specifically test? Use the sentence *"I want to make sure that _______"*, for example some tests I could see written for that code could be *"I want to make sure that `LoansDomainTrace.Trace.Error` gets called on exception but the original exception is still bubbled up unmodified"* and *"I want to make sure that `VerifyUser(` can be called with a valid input and throw no exceptions"*

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, one of the thing I want to get is to see one of the records that is message is null or it has some value.

Comment: Ok, go write a test that tests that logic. (Btw, your current code will never return sucessfully, `string.Format` has two placeholders in the string but you only pass in one value, it will always throw a `FormatException` every time). Also `using (loansContext.Database.Connection)` and `loansContext.Database.Connection.Open();` is wrong. it is not your responsability to dispose or manually open the connection, let `loansContext` do it. Also having `LoansContext loansContext = new LoansContext();` outside the using is a very weird design choice and should be avoided.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain how I let Context open and close the connection? Can you please explain it more.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I like to unit test my method logic and then isolate the code I want to test (in your case VerifyUser) from external resources (e.g. DBs). I good option is with some sort of [in-memory EF provider](http://hwyfwk.com/blog/2013/10/15/testable-data-access-at-every-level/), however a much more common way is to abstract away your EF implementation e.g. with some sort of repository pattern. Without this isolation any tests you write are integration, not unit tests.